eTA status still 'Not Started' over 24 hours after application
I applied for an ETA yesterday. When I use the ETA status checker provided on the IRCC webpage, it states that my application has been received, and that my 'final decision' is still 'not started'. In the past, I have received my ETA in minutes. For context, this is the first time I apply for an ETA since I received my canadian work permit.
Does anyone have any information that could explain the delay? Or any idea of what to do now?

See Should I apply for an eTA or a visa when I apply for a work permit?:

No. Depending on your citizenship, you may need an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA) or a visitor visa, as well as a work permit. Your eTA or visa will be issued to you at the same time as your work permit. You do not need to apply separately or to pay an additional fee.

Did your work permit not come with a document explaining this?

No. I got my work permit from within Canada while I was still a student, and never received anything about an ETA.
